# Print words from the corresponding line numbers

Tags: file, python-2.7, printing, words

Hello Everyone,
                   I have two files File1 and File2 which has the following data.

```
File1:

 TOPIC:topic_0 30063951.0
 2 19195200.0

 1 7586580.0

 3 2622580.0

TOPIC:topic_1 17201790.0
1 15428200.0

2 917930.0

10 670854.0
```

and so on..There are 15 topics and each topic have their respective weights. And the first column like 2,1,3 are the numbers which have corresponding words in file2. For example,

```
File 2 has:

   1 i

   2 new

   3 percent

   4 people 

   5 year

   6 two

   7 million

   8 president

   9 last

   10 government
```

and so on.. There are about 10,470 lines of words. So, in short I should have the corresponding words in the first column of file1 instead of the line numbers. My output should be like:

```
TOPIC:topic_0 30063951.0

new 19195200.0

i 7586580.0

percent 2622580.0

TOPIC:topic_1 17201790.0

i 15428200.0

new 917930.0

government 670854.0
```

My Code:

```
import sys
d1 = {}
n = 1

with open("ap_vocab.txt") as in_file2:
     for line2 in in_file2:
            #print n, line2
            d1[n] = line2[:-1]
            n = n + 1

with open("ap_top_t15.txt") as in_file:
     for line1 in in_file:
            columns = line1.split(' ')
            firstwords = columns[0]
            #print firstwords[:-8]
            if firstwords[:-8] == 'TOPIC':
                    print columns[0], columns[1]
            elif firstwords[:-8] != '\n':
                    num = columns[0]
                    print d1[n], columns[1]
```

This code is running when I type print d1[2], columns[1] giving the second  word in file2 for all the lines. But when the above code is printed, it is giving an error

```
KeyError: 10472
```

there are 10472 lines of words in the file2. Please help me with what I should do to rectify this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line is the error being traced back to?

Comment: The last line of the file 2 which as all the words. The last line in the code print d1[n], columns[1] is giving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `for` loop, `n` is incremented with each line until reaching a final value of 10472. You are only setting values for `d1[n]` up to *10471* however, as you have placed the increment **after** you set `d1` for your given `n`, with these two lines:

```
        d1[n] = line2[:-1]
        n = n + 1
```

Then on the line

```
print d1[n], columns[1]
```

in your second `for` loop (for `in_file`), you are attempting to access `d1[10472]`, which evidently doesn't exist. Furthermore, you are defining `d1` as an empty Dictionary, and then attempting to access it as if it were a list, such that even if you fix your increment you will not be able to access it like that. You must either use a list with `d1 = []`, or will have to implement an `OrderedDict` so that you can access the "last" key as dictionaries are typically unordered in Python.

You can either:

Alter your increment so that you ***do*** set a value for `d1` in the `d1[10472]` position, or simply set the value for the last position *after* your `for` loop.

Depending on what you are attempting to print out, you could replace your last line with

```
print d1[-1], columns[1]
```

to print out the value for the final index position you currently have set.

Comment: oh.. that's interesting. Sorry am new to coding, so where do I edit the code to stop it from going to the 10472nd line? Please help

Comment: Am sorry. I am totally new to coding. I tried setting while n < 10472: and run the rest of the code with print d1[-1] and it is still showing a Key Error. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: `while n < 10472` would not do ***anything*** as the `while` loop would run until `n` was set to 10472 (which is what currently happens). Using a `while` loop is completely unnecessary and I would advise you use one of the two approaches I outlined in my answer, however if you really felt like using one you would want `while n < 10471`

Comment: printing with d1[-1] is still giving me a keyerror of -1.

Comment: @Krupa_Raghu Ahh I just realized you defined `d1` as a dictionary, not a list. Do you want a dictionary or a list? Because if you want a list, then you can use `d1 = []` to define an empty list and ***then*** you won't get an index error, or you can use an `OrderedDict` as dictionaries are typically unordered.